# MATLAB image processing - edge detection algorithm

Tags: image, matlab

[image]

Hi, first picture represents the damage and delamination that follows

What I want to do is remove the intact area and only visualize the damage area that is marked by black curves (I want everything to be white, or blank except the damage area)

[image]

[image]

I tried Thresholding method but doesn't seem to be effective
So I found out that histogram equalization and laplacian of gaussian filter are useful for edge detection image processing.

- Are there any other image processing tool to get what I want?
- Will histogram equalization or laplacian of gaussian filter be good enough?
- Any tips are welcome!

Thanks in advance guys

Comment: I would try starting from the middle of the intact area, using Active Contour method.

Comment: laplacian of gaussian filter sounds like a good idea - have you tried to implement it? Also, you know about `edge()`?